# Best tool for Code-Analyzement or Code-Review

Tags: c#, asp.net

Which code-Analyzer or Code-Review tool do you suggest ,

For Analyzing **DotNet 2.0 & 3.5** code and getting

*All classes , Methods , Properties , Instances , Definition ,
Databases & and their relation to code ,*

I want to **get print-ready Information** about codes & projects ,

( *here I dont mean a tool for testing the code & structures* )

Is there anyone with similar specifications ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/)?

Answer (score 3):

[Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) is very good and free. The [Code Metrics](http://www.codeplex.com/reflectoraddins/Wiki/View.aspx?title=CodeMetrics&referringTitle=Home) add-in will give you good quality metrics. This may not give you the print-readiness you need.

[doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org/) can analyze your source code and output documentation listing all classes, namespaces, call trees, dependencies, etc. This should give you printability.

Comment: +1 for Doxygen( pronounced as docs-ee-gen not D-oxygen). Very elegant, especially if you install GraphViz package

Answer (score 1):

[FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476(vs.80).aspx)

it gives an analysis in:
    * Correctness
    * Library design
    * Localization
    * Naming conventions
    * Performance
    * Security

Comment: FxCop I think gives you analysis with Testing focus , Isn't it ?

Comment: The main problem of using FxCop is it will take only .dll files for code analysis not the actual code

Answer (score 0):

You should look at Atlassian Crucible for peer code review.  Doing reviews online keeps them moving forward with minimal distraction for your team.

http://www.atlassian.com/software/crucible/